# Looping through the copy of a list and still getting an InvalidOperationException

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a Sub that is called very frequently, while at the same time a secondary thread change the values in all the Lists it uses. Obviously, that would cause an `InvalidOperationException`, so I put a `.ToList` in the `For Each` loop so it copies the List before looping through it. That didn't work, and I was getting `InvalidOperationException: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`" (and by the way, I don't know why, but this exception is only thrown when running the app outside of VS, making it very difficult to debug. Note that the error still exists when debugging the app on VS, only the exception isn't thrown). Then I tried explicitly copying the List, with no success, the error still persists. This is the faulty Sub:

```
Private Sub MasmorraPictureBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MasmorraPictureBox.Paint
    Dim c As New Integer
    Dim DGridCopy As List(Of Point) = DGrid.ToList
    Dim DPointsCopy As List(Of Point) = DPoints.ToList
    Dim DGridColCopy As List(Of Brush) = DGridCol.ToList
    Dim DPointsTextCopy As List(Of String) = DPointsText.ToList
    For Each Point As Point In DGridCopy
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(DGridColCopy(c), Point.X, Point.Y, 35, 35)
        c += 1
    Next
    c = 0
    For Each Point As Point In DPointsCopy
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, Point.X - 5, Point.Y - 5, 10, 10)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DPointsTextCopy(c), MyFont, Brushes.Black, Point.X - 5, Point.Y + 10, StrFormat)
        c += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**: The problem was already corrected by declaring the copies as `.ToList` of the original lists. I thought it wasn't because there was still some errors, but as I said previously, the debugger isn't throwing `InvalidOperationException`'s (even though they were ocurring), so I only discovered the error wasn't in this Sub anymore when I ran the app outside of VS in order to discover which line was throwing it as asked in the comments.

Comment: I can't see where you tried to put `.ToList()` in the code

Comment: `DGridCopy` and the other 2 are not **copies** of the originals.  All you did was create new references to the original lists.

Comment: @har07, as I said in the OP, I tried using `.ToList` on all the lists in the sub, but that didn't work: I was still getting the Exception. Then I tried explicitly copying them, which didn't work either. And @Plutonix, I don't think so.

Comment: @Plutonix Oh, now I see why you say that, the code I posted doesn't have `.ToList` when copying the variables. Sorry, I'll edit it. And, to clarify, what I did before was `For Each Point As Point in DGrid.ToList`, which didn't work either, and then I changed it in order to explicitly copy the Lists before the loop starts. Still getting the error.

Comment: Show us the declarations for `DGrid` and the other originals.

Comment: And on what line are you getting this error?

Comment: Whops. I started the app outside of VS in order to see which line was causing the exception (because, as I said, the debugger doesn't catch that exception), as @RBarryYoung asked, and I discovered that it wasn't this Sub anymore. I'm really sorry guys, and thanks for trying to help. And by the way, does anyone knows why the debugger doesn't catch `InvalidOperationException`s?

Comment: It catches them fine for me.  I suspect that your troubles with the debugger are more from multi-threading and how the IDE and debugger interact with it.  I've always had problems figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to a list while reading from it at the same time. That's a race. `ToList` counts as a reader because *anything* looking at the list is a reader.

Use proper synchronization like locks. Or immutable structures.

Answer (score 0):

`For Each` loops call the enumerator of the list and enumerators don't like to be enumerated while the underlying collection is being changed (`InvalidOperationException` is thrown if this happens). Accessing list items directly does not throw an exception, only using the lists enumerator does.

Replace the `For Each` loops by simple `For` loops and access the list items through the indexer. As long as no items are removed from the lists, you should not tap into an invalid index. But of course the contents of the list might change under way, so this is not really thread safe.

The remarks in [IEnumerator.MoveNext Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an
>   InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Concurrent access to any shared variable when one access is a write is unsafe. Furthermore the List class does not guarantee what you claim. What evidence are the claims based on? Sorry for not commenting initially.

Comment: If the points read from the list change while the picture is being drawn, the picture might show parts of the old frame and parts of the new frame. Depending on the circumstances this might be acceptable.